# MailServer that doesn't store any data outside database?

Tags: 12.04, email, mail, mail-server, dovecot

Question:

Is there any OpenSource (MIT/BSD/LGPL license) mail server that doesn't store any of its data (except database connection string/sql query scripts) outside a database ?

I looked at Dovecot, which depends on postfix, and it (or postfix respectively) does store data other than logfiles outside the database, which is unacceptable.

Is there any mail server that does exactly this (with the mentionend licenses) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for mail server here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_mail_servers

And since this is open source software why don't you just delete code responsible storage of log files outside of database.